# Can I improve compression of a consecutive file based on compression of previous files

Tags: compression

I have two binary files that are very similar.

I wonder if there's a compression algorithm (or a tool) that can use one file as a dictionary for the other one.

Example:

File 1:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer
```

File 2:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor SIT amet consectetuer
```

Dictionary generated based on similarities between the files:

```
A = "Lorem ipsum dolor "
B = " amet consectetuer"
```

Compressed File 2 based on the dictionary:

```
`A`SIT`B`
```

Is there such a tool or at least an algorithm that I can implement?

Answer (score 0):

I found that rsync can produce (very quickly!) a patch to be applied to a file:

```
rsync --only-write-batch=patch to-file from.file
```

That can be compressed:

```
xz -k -9 -c -z patch > patch.xz
```

To apply the patch:

```
./patch.sh to-file
```

For the files that I tested (250MB tarballs), I was able to get a compressed patch of 2-16MB, while the compressed tarball was 40MB.